# How to display wishlist in JTable?

Tags: java

I've just been learning Java recently and have a math problem. The requirement is to enter the displayed data into the table. Then filter out the list of mssv with DiemTb>7. But i don't know how to do.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJyzJ.jpg]

This is my code:

```
private  ArrayList<Student> list;
 DefaultTableModel model, hocbong;
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    list=new ArrayList<>()  ;
    model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    
}
```

and

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Student s=new Student();
    s.setMssv(txtmssv.getText());
    s.setDiem1(Float.parseFloat(txtdiem1.getText()));
    s.setDiem2(Float.parseFloat(txtdiem2.getText()));
    s.setDiem3(Float.parseFloat(txtdiem3.getText()));
    
    
    list.add(s); // them vao danh sach SV
    showResult();
    
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
              
     
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
}                                        

public void showResult(){
    Student s = list.get(list.size()-1);
    model.addRow(new Object[]{
         s.getMssv(), s.getDiem1(),s.getDiem2(), s.getDiem3(), s.getDiemTB()
    });}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then filter out the list of mssv with DiemTb>7.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a complete working example.

The example shows how to use a regex filter on String.

However, read the `RowFilter` API as it also includes a number filter.

I guess you would use something like:

```
RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, 7);
```